# How is MediaWiki text table connected to the category tables?

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

I am trying to find corresponding text records for a category.

For example if I have the ID 5 for a "categorylinks" record, how would I find which texts go into that category?

Comment: By text records, do you mean the title of the pages in that category? Or the actual text of the pages that are in a category?

Comment: The actual texts, i.e. the "text" table in MediaWiki -- how is that table related to "category" or "categorylinks" tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I'm still not sure if you are asking for the text of a category page or the text of the pages in a category so here's both:

**Text of a category page:**

```
select old_text from text, revision, page, categorylinks
where rev_text_id = old_id
    and rev_id = page_latest
    and page_namespace = 14
    and page_title = cl_to
    and cl_from = <cl_from entry in categorylinks table>
```

**Text of a page in a category:**

```
select old_text from text, revision, page, categorylinks
where rev_text_id = old_id
    and rev_id = page_latest
    and page_id = cl_from
    and cl_to = <cl_to entry in categorylinks table>
```

**More explanation:**

Basically, in categorylinks, the `cl_title` is the title of the category page. So you can look that up in the page table using `page_title` and `page_namespace` = 14 (the category namespace). Once you have the correct page, the `page_latest` field for that row equals the `rev_id` in the revision table. This gives you the latest revision for the category page. The revision table has a `rev_text_id` field which equals the `old_id` field in the text table. `old_text` in the text table is your text.

Any time you want the text for a page it basically works like this. Find the page database record. Then: `page.page_latest = revision.rev_id and revision.rev_text_id = text.old_id`.

See also: [The MediaWiki database schema](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/MediaWiki_database_schema_1-19_%28r102798%29.svg/2193px-MediaWiki_database_schema_1-19_%28r102798%29.svg.png).

Comment: I'm unable to retrieve text for a given CategoryLink. Are you sure this works right?

Comment: It fetches the wrong text. I fetches the text for the top category link's page, I'm looking into fetching texts for every category and output a custom formatted CATEGORY -> TEXT output.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you are asking for so I updated the answer. Try which ever query you need and let me know if it works.